# Ubuntu 18.04 Top Panel only on one monitor

Tags: panel, 18.04

I've just upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04 and now I only have the top panel (where Activities, clock, etc. sit) on my primary monitor, is there any way to replicate this so I can have it on both like in Unity?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check out the Gnome Shell Extension [Multi Monitors Add-On](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/921/multi-monitors-add-on/).

Just to mention it: A previous version of this post referenced to the [Multiple Monitor Panels Extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/323/multiple-monitor-panels), which isn't working properly in 18.04.

Comment: I installed this extension and it didn't automatically do what I was expecting. Is there some way to configure it? The readme on the github page was spare on details.

Comment: The Add-On comes with a few settings => https://pasteboard.co/HM520GHh.png. You can access the configuration at https://extensions.gnome.org/local/

Comment: for me it caused an error, making two panels on one screen

Comment: In Ubuntu 20.04, the bar does get displayed on all monitors, but not its contents (e.g. the clock)

Answer (score 11):

In Ubuntu 18.04 there is an inbuilt setting for replicating Doc (EDIT: this answer dosen't answer the asked questions but would like to help people in replicating doc for multiple monitors so just kept it here):

**Open Settings >> Dock >> Show on: All Displays**

Done :)

Comment: That's the dock, not the top panel.

Comment: oh I got confused by the doc setting

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 18.04, go to "Settings", "Devices", "Screen Display". Click on "Primary Display". Choose the display you want the top panel to appear. After doing this, you may need to re-adjust where the dock is positioned using "Settings", "Dock".

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem and solution for me was:

1. open : **open setings>>Apperance** and in option **Show on:**
   first change **all displays** it shows top bar and activities bar on all monitors and then switch to **Built-in display(Primary Display)** that switch all on built-in display.

Comment: I'm having trouble following this answer. Could you please clarify it? For example, you could put the menu items in bold text so it is clearer exactly what we need to click. A screenshot might also help!